# Using $routeProvider with <form action> and <input name>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use **$routeProvider** with dynamic paths when I make a GET with a `<form action="results">` and `<input name="query">`. The url becomes `www.website.com/results?query=input`. But from what I understand, dynamic paths don't work unless the colon in the path for **$routeProvider** immediately follows the slash i.e.

```
$routeProvider.when('/:thing', templateUrl: 'result.html', controller:'aController');
```

This does not work

```
$routeProvider.when('/results?query=:input', templateUrl: 'result.html', controller:'aController');
```

How do handle the path parameter for when()?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

Comment: but how does that help with $routeProvider detecting the path?

Comment: Are you going to be rendering the "result.html" every time no matter what "query=" results to?

If so just check the $location.search to see what the value is and create an Angular service to fetch the data depending on which query returns. 

Bind that response from your angular service to your $scope then wire to a view. Your view should be generic. So your angular service should do all the work to decide what your data looks like.

If you go this route then just use "/results" as your path and the controller should make the call to the service to get your data, then take that data wire it up